# How to install a Live Wallpaper on Lock Screen for Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

On my Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.2.2), I am trying to install a Live Wallpaper on the Lock Screen. Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing software on your device, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click 'Set Wallpaper' on the phone and select 'Lock Screen' there is no way to set live wallpaper. If you select Home AND Lockscreen the option is there for Live Wallpaper. Looks like a quirk of the S4. The S3 does the same thing!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it!